# Having difficulty with Summation notation

Tags: summation, permutations, notation

So, I wanted to evaluate the sum:$$\sum\sum\sum\sum_{1\leq i\leq j \leq k\leq w \leq n}1$$
The indices in the question were actually written below all the summation signs but I have no idea how to do that. Anyways, I was wondering if this is just a symmetric sum which simply takes a value for each index. It would be much appreciated if anyone could expand this sum. I tried to find it on the web but there weren't any helpful results. Thanks!

Edit: The sum is actually $\underset{1\leq i\leq j\leq k\leq w\leq n}{\sum\sum\sum\sum} 1$

Comment: I think the latex that you were intending  is $\underset{1\leq i\leq j\leq k\leq w\leq n}{\sum\sum\sum\sum} 1$. Although, I think you technically only need one summation symbol, so like $\underset{1\leq i\leq j\leq k\leq w\leq n}{\sum} 1$.

Comment: @AlanAbraham yes I meant the first one.... I did not know that the 1st and the 2nd one were identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of summation sums the value $1$ for all integer tuples $(i,j,k,w)$ such that the condition $1\leq i\leq j\leq k\leq w\leq n$ is satisfied. Essentially, it is just counting the number of quadruples such that $ i\leq j\leq k\leq w\leq n$.

<s>While we could technically expand each summation starting from the inside, this gets rather tedious especially the more summations you expand.</s>

Instead we will solve the whole entire summation at once using stars and bars. Denote the integer variables $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5$ such that
$$\begin{cases}i=a_1\\ j=i+a_2\\ k=j+a_3\\ w=k+a_4\\ n=w+a_5\end{cases}$$
It is evident that we must have $a_1\geq 1$ and $a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5\geq 0$.

Moreover, we have that the number of solutions to $ i\leq j\leq k\leq w\leq n$ is equivalent to the number of solutions to
$$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=n$$
This is true because we can form a bijection from each valid quadruple $(i,j,k,w)$ to each valid tuple $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)$$

To find the number of solutions to
$$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=n$$
we must first make each term on the LHS range through all nonnegative integers in order to use the stars and bars formula. Since $a_1$ is the only variable that does not range through all nonnegative integers (as it is restricted to exclude $0$), note that
$$(a_1-1)+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=n-1$$
does meet all these conditions. The number of solutions, by stars and bars, is $\binom{n-1+5-1}{5-1}=\boxed{\binom{n+3}{4}}$.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the sum

$$\sum_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq w \leq n} a_{ijkw}$$

where $a_{ijkw} = 1$ for all relevant values of the subscripts, which means you're essentially just adding $1+1+1+\ldots+1$, for however many terms there are in the range $1 \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq w$. To give you a bit of a start, consider these versions for one and two subscript:

- $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} 1 = \sum_{i = 1}^n 1 + \ldots + 1 = n$, since you're just adding 1 $n$ times over.
- $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq n} 1 = \sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{i = 1}^j 1 = \sum_{j = 1}^n j = 1 + 2 + \ldots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, since the inner summation is just the same as the one above, but with an upper limit of $j$ instead of $n$, and then adding consecutive integers gives the triangular numbers (a pretty well-known result).

Can you see how to extend that to three, and then all four summations?

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks for the visualization with smaller cases!

Comment: No problem! My answer is definitely more about helping understand what the sum is doing, but the other answers are much better for finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

While my original answer is what I first came up with, I'd also like to point out another approach, as I have realized that it is actually simpler to just expand the summations **if** you make use of the hockey stick identity
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{k+i}{k}=\binom{n+k+1}{n}$$

We can break apart our sum into the following nested summation
$$\sum_{w=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^w\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{i=1}^j 1$$
Starting with the inner sum, this simplifies to
$$\sum_{w=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^w\sum_{j=1}^k\binom{j}{1}$$
Making repeated use of the hockey stick identity, the sum simplifies to
$$\sum_{w=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^w\binom{k+1}{2}$$
$$\sum_{w=1}^n\binom{w+2}{3}$$
$$\binom{n+3}{4}$$